# How do I get gold acorns?

Tags: animal-hot-springs

I have figured out how to get/use normal acorns to improve the hot springs experience for the various animals who visit. But it looks like there are some things that require gold acorns, and so far, I've not gotten any. I thought maybe I had to buy them with real world money, but I can't see anywhere in game to do that, either.

How do I get gold acorns so that I can make my hot spring super awesome?

Answer (score 2):

You can start collecting golden acorns only after you have unlocked the sauna.
By grilling food on the sauna, and subsequently giving it to your guests, they will occasionally give you a golden acorn.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [beginners guide](https://www.levelwinner.com/animal-hot-springs-beginners-guide-tips-cheats-tricks/):

> collect the golden acorns once you level up your animals’ VIP status to the highest possible level